# "Not responding" message if the user clicks in the SplashScreen | WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, mvvm

I have an WPF application which takes a little bit to start up, I have a SplashScreen which tells to the user to just wait for a bit till the application is completly loaded. So far so good.

The problem is the user (like always), and if he starts clicking desesperatly everywhere in the SplashScreen, he gets the typical Windows™ message saying "This program is not responding", in this messagebox he can choose to close the program, this will close another process where I make all the loading stuff, but not the WPF app. Then the WPF Application starts, but you cannot do anything on it. This behaviour doesnt happen if the user clicks just a couple of times.

So my questions are, Is it possible either to block this message from Windows™, either block the user interaction with the SplashScreen?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: Eventually, your users will choose *"close"* once or twice, then realize they shouldn't. Or you could display *"Please, do not desperately click on this splashscreen"* on your splashscreen

Comment: I guess that you are doing the 'Loading' on the UI thread, and that blocks the UI interactions. When that happens, it says 'Not Responding' when you click it a lot. Change the Loading part on a different thread, or use async.

Comment: That makes sense @LupuSilviu, the thing is, this loading stuff is in the App.xaml.cs, if I start another thread for the loading,  the UI will appear and will not be functional either

Comment: So, you want to do the loading without showing the Window? You can do that if you remove the StartupUri path, and display the window from code using window.Show(). You need to post some code if you want mode help.

Comment: Display a slash screen window, intiialize your data on a background ground and then show the MainWindow.

Comment: Understood, thanks all for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

Any slow processes should be in a separate thread to the GUI. This will keep the GUI responsive to user input.

BTW, if you display a progress bar (even a fake one that just moves 1% every second) the user should be more patient as they can see that the application hasn't crashed.